# ASP.NET MVC3 + ActiveRecord + HasMany + Dictionary

Tags: nhibernate, dictionary, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to get a Dictionary data-structure in place for one of my ASP.NET MVC models. Essentially, I would like a hash-map of settings as key-value pairs. My code is similar to:

```
[ActiveRecord]
public class Blog extends ActiveRecordBase<Blog> {
  [Property]
  public IDictionary<string, string> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

However, I'm at a loss on how to implement this. I assume that I would need a DB table like BlogSettings with a key and value column; but I'm not clear on how to do this *without* creating another model.

NHibernate/ActiveRecord complain that:

```
A HasMany with type Map requires that you specify an 'Index', use the Index property Blog.Settings
```

I tried adding a dummy index (since I'm not clear on how to add indicies with ActiveRecord), like so:

```
  [Property(Index="")]
  public IDictionary<string, string> Settings { get; set; }
```

I didn't expect any change, but instead I got a second, different error message:

```
ActiveRecord tried to infer details about the relation Blog.Settings but it could not find information about the specified target type System.String. If you have mapped a Collection or Dictionary of value types, please make sure you have specified the Table property
```

My question is therefore: **What do I need to (code/DB wise) to set up my ActiveRecord model with a Dictionary of string key/value pairs as a single field, without creating a new class to encapsulate key-value pairs?**

Comment: just to be clear, you want to store a whole dictionary in a single field?

Comment: @Mauricio correct; that is my ideal design which I would like to implement, if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `IUserType`. [Here's one that implements](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/06/localized-property-with-nhibernate.html) a `IUserType` very similar to what you need.

Then use the `ColumnType` property of the `[Property]` attribute to reference the fully qualified type name of your `IUserType`.

Comment: This looks to be as much hassle (if not more) than making my own key-value-pair class.

Comment: @ashes999 if you want to store the whole dictionary *in a single field*, this is the only way. If you write your own key-value-pair class you'll have to use another table or separate fields.

Comment: I appreciate the comments; but from my perspective, that's a *lot* of code to write for something that should be relatively simple and automatic. I guess I'll go with a custom table then :/